# Raspberry PI emulator for windows with QEMU

Tags: raspbian, qemu

I am trying to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xiQX0YXYuqU) youtube video setting up PI emulator on my windows 10 machine. 
I am getting the following error :

```
D:\2019-09-26-raspbian-buster-full>qemu-system-arm -kernel kernel-qemu-4.4.34-jessie -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw init=/bin/bash" -drive"file=2019-09-26-raspbian-buster-full.img,index=0,media=disk,format=raw" -redir tcp:2222::22
qemu-system-arm: -drivefile=2019-09-26-raspbian-buster-full.img,index=0,media=disk,format=raw: invalid option

D:\2019-09-26-raspbian-buster-full>KERNEL=="sda", SYMLINK+="mmcblk0"
'KERNEL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

D:\2019-09-26-raspbian-buster-full>KERNEL=="sda?", SYMLINK+="mmcblk0pn"
'KERNEL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

D:\2019-09-26-raspbian-buster-full>KERNEL=="sda2", SYMLINK+="root"
'KERNEL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

D:\2019-09-26-raspbian-buster-full>qemu-img.exe resize 2019-09-26-raspbian-buster-full.img +4G
WARNING: Image format was not specified for '2019-09-26-raspbian-buster-full.img' and probing guessed raw.
         Automatically detecting the format is dangerous for raw images, write operations on block 0 will be restricted.
         Specify the 'raw' format explicitly to remove the restrictions.
Image resized.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Youtube videos for installation are a no go. Please note why [What's wrong with “I followed this tutorial” kind of questions?](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/whats-wrong-with-i-followed-this-tutorial-kind-of-questions/2198#2198).

Comment: dont download the latest use 2017 released builds or use buster kernel. you can find out more here https://github.com/dhruvvyas90/qemu-rpi-kernel